# Non-clustered join performs better than clustered

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I ran the following query on a clustered and non-clustered and observed the results of the trace and found that the non-clustered performed better than the clustered, when I was expecting the query run on the clustered to perform much better and I was just wondering why the non-clustered performed better than the clustered? The clustered contained two tables and the clustered index is on the column `cid`

Non-clustered join query trace:

[image]

Non-clustered join query explain plan:

[image]

Clustered join query trace:

[image]

Clustered join query explain plan:

[image]

Create cluster sql:

```
CREATE CLUSTER booking_customer (cid NUMBER(16)) PCTUSED 85 PCTFREE 5 SIZE 5K;
```

Comment: Can you post the `create cluster` statement you used?

Comment: Is both tables in this cluster?
Could you please post their DDL-s  as well

Comment: Yes they were both added to the cluster, in the explain plan you can see it's using the cluster. And what is DDL?

Comment: A difference of 0.01 seconds isn't significant and can be explained by unrelated factors like server load and caching.  Comparing such small differences requires averaging multiple runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cluster is really intended for optimising nested loop joins, by physically co-locating the relevant rows in the tables that are to be joined. Therefore it is excellent at retrieving small quantities of joined data, as an OLTP system might require.

When you are equi-joining two complete tables, the hash join is the most efficient because its cost generally doesn't exceed the sum of the table scans of the two tables (as long as the join doesn't spill to disk, in which case equi-partitining can help), and a full scan is the most efficient way of reading the entirety two tables.

The hash join is inefficient on tables in a cluster because the two full table scans have to be two full cluster scans, and the cluster is more than twice the size of both tables added together (due to space wastage).

So a hash join on two tables in a cluster may well be less efficient than a nested loop join between them, and will certainly be less efficient than if the tables were stored in conventional non-clustered tables.

Answer (score 1):

DDL - Data Definition Language, it refers to the command you used to create the mentioned objects.
I'm going on a limb here but I'm guessing that both tables are not so big. In that case it makes since that the non-clustered join might perform faster, since it is not using the index and therefore can read the data in chunks (an abaility that index based queries simply don't have).
Also, since you are reading both tables in full, the Hash join generated by the non-clustered join should be much faster than the nested loops join chosen by the clustered join. Nested loops works best when the father table is heavily filtered.